# How to express mutually exclusive inheritance in UML?

Tags: uml

How to exemplify that a class can inherit either of two super-classes, but not both?

[image]

The class **Property** can either represent a ***Set*** of numbers, or a ***Cardinal*** number, BUT not both at the same type.

Comment: You are not using generalization but realization in your diagram.

Comment: Thank you for the correction @Thomas Kilian ?
I have edited the fig.

Comment: @Hairi: the original diagram is now a broken link. Could you please restore it for others who might have the same kind of question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your sub classing is upside down. You need a `Set Property` and a `Cardinal Property` that specialize `Property`. If those subclasses also have characteristics of `Set` and `Cardinal`, you could subclass those as well.