# How to Depict Either/Or Inheritance in a UML diagram?

Tags: class, inheritance, uml, class-diagram

So lets say I have a class CelebrityDog. CelebrityDog can either be a BigDog or a SmallDog depending on what the user wants.

It will inherit the properties of one of them, but not of both. How would I depict this in a UML diagram?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to express mutually exclusive inheritance in UML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38830845/how-to-express-mutually-exclusive-inheritance-in-uml)

Answer (score 1):

**UML perspective**

I am sorry to come with an unpleasant answer, but this is not possible in UML according to the UML 2.5 standard, section 9.2.4.1:

> Generalizations define generalization/specialization relationships
>   between Classifiers. Each Generalization relates a specific Classifier
>   to a more general Classifier.
>  
>   ...
>   An instance of a Classifier **is also an** (indirect) **instance of each of
>   its generalizations**. Any Constraints applying to instances of the
>   generalizations also apply to instances of the Classifier.

In other words, an inheritance relation in UML is a relationship between a generalization and a specialization.  A class can be the specialization of several more generalization class but always in the same time (i.e. multiple inheritance.

**Design perspective**

I'll add to the already unpleasant answer, that this is anyways a very bad desgin, that you will not be able to implement in most of the mainstream languages.

You can improve with a model that is closer to the reality of the relationsips:

- `CelebrityDog` is a `Dog` (inheritance, this is always true)
- `Dog` has a `DogSize` (association, i.e. composition when implementing) which can change over time
- `DogSize` can be specialized into `BigDogSize` or `SmallDogSize`

Et voilà !

Comment: if you place xor constraint between the generalizations (which you can do), then imho any instance of the classifier would inherit only from one parent, unless the semantics of generalizations ignore constraints

Comment: @Peter indeed, the UML semantics consider that the generalization always applies and hence the xor constraint is invalid !  The constraints are not allowed to contradict the meaning of the model.  It's like with associations: if you have two optional (e.g. 0..1) associations, you can have an xor constraint between the two.  However, if you have two mandatory (e.g. 1..1) associations, the xor is invalid, because it contradicts the cardinalities that shall always apply.

Answer (score 0):

Dog is the top level class.  It does not contain a size attribute.
CelebrityDog derives from Dog (as do normal, EverydayDogs).
BigDog and SmallDog derive from CelebrityDog.  Perhaps change their class names to BigCelebrityDog and SmallCelebrityDog.

It is possible to use multiple inheritance to solve this, but that can be confusing.